# yii2 starter kit console commands doesn't work

Tags: yii2

I have yii2 starter kit application and I am trying to run console commands but they're not working. For example I am staying in console folder and run command php yii migrate/up(or any other commands none of them run) but I see only this

[image]
[image]

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: you need to provide the name for the migration and you have to run the commands from the root of the application not inside the `/console` folder stay on the root folder and run the command `./yii migrate/create the_name_of_migration`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, i have tried run this command from project's root 
```./yii migrate/create test_table
Could not open input file: ./yii```
or
```yii migrate/create test_table
Could not open input file: yii```

Comment: i dont think you are on the root can you share a print screen of the directory where you are running the command from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue, a programmer before me, added this code below to `common/config/base.php`

```
    'request' => [
        'class' => 'common\components\lang\LangRequest',
    ],
```

I have moved this class to request section in `frontend/config/web.php`. And remove `request` section from `common/config/base.php`. Now console commands working perfectly.